# Org mode regex search view

Tags: org-mode, regular-expressions, search

Upon reading [Search View](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Search-view)

It state that

```
You can incrementally adjust a boolean search with the following keys

[   Add a positive search word
]   Add a negative search word
{   Add a positive regular expression
}   Add a negative regular expression
```

Try regex match algorithms

[image]

it return many non-matched results/

What's the problem?

[image]

Comment: I proposed a slight change to the Org documentation which hopefully makes the meaning of the keys more clear.

Comment: Ty, very very unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those keys to incrementally adjust the search refer to the user interface in the agenda buffer that appears after a `org-agenda-search-view` (typically bound to `C-c C-a s`.)

Further there is the search string which can be conveniently changed with the mentioned keys.  The search string is applied not only to the headlines but also to the content of the subtrees.

The info manual (info "(org) Search view") says: "It is particularly useful to find notes."

So I think the answer is that there is no real problem.